# What does $F = 2^W$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading the book Reasoning about uncertainty and having some problems with the notation.

$F = 2^W$ where $W$ is a set and $F$ an algebra.

What this mean?

Comment: $2^W$cis standard notation for the set of subsets of $W$. Your book may assume additional algebraic structure, the usual Boolean one.

Comment: Powerset, surely?

Comment: Yeah, set of subsets or power set.

Comment: In general, $A^B$ is used for the set of all functions $f:B \to A$.  Can you see why this agrees with the power set definition when $A = 2$?

Comment: Also, viewing $F=2^W$ as the set of all functions $f:W\to \Bbb Z/2$ reveals the algebra structure of $F$ immediately. (Unless one means "algebra" in the measure settings.)

Answer (score 0):

Means the **Power set**.

i.e.

if $W = \{w_1, w_2, w_3\}$ then

$2^W = \{\emptyset,\{w_1\},\{w_2\},\{w_3\},\{w_1,w_2\},\{w_1,w_3\},\{w_2,w_3\},\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}\}$